# Adding Spring module in JBOSS EAP 6.2

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jboss

jboss startup with error thats why application showing 404, where is tomcat running perfectly with same war.i am using jboss EAP 6.2, spring 4.3 ,java 7.

```
15:03:40,846 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag in Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/RequestContextAwareTag (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 47 more

15:03:40,853 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag in Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/RequestContextAwareTag (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 47 more

15:03:40,857 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."OnlineRegistration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."OnlineRegistration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "OnlineRegistration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/RequestContextAwareTag (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TryCatchFinally from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @3ff33ecb (finder: local module finder @7a9fa239 (roots: E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules,E:\software\jboss-eap-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 47 more
```

i thing **jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar** should contain TryCatchFinally class but in this case class not found.Do i need more configuration after adding spring module or  jboss library  conflicting with war lib?

please let me know if jboss 6.2 is not support spring 4.x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you defined a module org.springframework.spring, but you didn't define a dependency to javax.servlet.jsp.api within that module.xml.

JBoss doesn't add dependencies to your module automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Erhard Siegl.